# $\psi(x)-x$ on average

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

This is a reference question:

Let $\psi(x)$ be the psi-Chebyshev function. Is there any unconditional result in the literature that proves that there exists $0<a<2$ such that
$$
\int_2^x (\psi(y)-y)^2 \mathrm dy =O(x^{a})
?$$

Comment: Morally, this shouldn't be true. Assuming the Riemann hypothesis, $|\psi(y) - y|$ is about $y^{1/2+\epsilon}$, so your integral should be $\int^x y^{1+2 \epsilon} dy \approx x^{2+2 \epsilon}$. And, if RH fails, then $\phi(y)-y$ oscillates more wildly than this. But I don't know a reference saying this can't be true, so I'm waiting for someone else to post one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Impossible as this would imply that $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}+\frac1{s-1}$ is analytic on $\Re(s)\ge 1/2$.

Your bound
$$\int_1^x |\psi(y)-y|^2 dy = O(x^a)$$ for some $a < 2$ implies (with Cauchy-Schwarz inequality) that $$\int_x^{2x} (\psi(y)-y)dy = O(x^{a/2+1/2}) \implies\int_1^2 (\psi(xt)-xt)dt = O(x^{a/2-1/2})
$$
i.e.
$$s\int_1^\infty\int_1^2 (\psi(tx)-tx)dt x^{-s-1}dx= \left(\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}-\frac{s}{s-1}\right)\int_1^2 t^s dt-f(s)$$

extends analytically from $\Re(s) > 1$ to $\Re(s) > a/2-1/2$ which is absurd.

(where $f(s)=s\int_1^2 t^s\int_1^t x^{-s}dxdt$ is an irrelevant entire term)

Comment: I am not sure I follow the last identity of integrals but I am surely making a mistake. Please correct me but what I get is the slightly different $$  s\int_1^\infty\int_1^2 (\psi(tx)-tx)dt x^{-s-1}dx=s\int_1^2 t^s\int_t^\infty \frac{\psi(u)-u}{u^{s+1}}\mathrm d u \mathrm dt.$$

Comment: @Dr.Pi Yes and for $t\le 2,\Re(s)> 1$, $s\int_t^\infty (\psi(u)-u)u^{-s-1}du=(-\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)-s/(s-1))$

Comment: Again I am not sure if this is true. The right hand side in the last equation probably has $t^{1-s} s/(s-1)$ instead of $s/s(s-1)$ but I am not sure-let me know what you think!

Comment: ps. maybe all of these should work with $\psi(y)-[y]$ instead of $\psi(y)-y$.

Comment: $-\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\ge 1} \Lambda(n)n^{-s}$ $=\sum_{n\ge 1}s\int_n^\infty \Lambda(n) x^{-s-1}dx$ $=s\int_1^\infty  (\sum_{n\le x} \Lambda(n)) x^{-s-1}dx$ $=s\int_1^\infty \psi(x)x^{-s-1}dx$. Then substract $\frac{s}{s-1}=s\int_1^\infty x\, x^{-s-1}dx$ to both side. All this needs $\Re(s) > 1$ for absolute convergence and so on, but your $O(x^a)$ bound then allows to extend analyticaly to $\Re(s)\ge 1/2$ which is absurd (given the many poles on $\Re(s)=1/2$).

Comment: Yes I get that but I still think that there is a mistake because one has instead $int_t^\infty x x^{-s-1} \mathrm d x$ instead.

Comment: @Dr.Pi Oh you are right, thanks. Obviously it doesn't change the argument as this is an additional entire term

Answer (score 28):

In Theorem 1 of

*Brent, Richard P.; Platt, David J.; Trudgian, Timothy S.*, [**The mean square of the error term in the prime number theorem**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2021.09.016),  [ZBL07569752](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07569752).

it is shown that for sufficiently large $x$ one has the lower bound
$$ \int_x^{2x} |\psi(y)-y|^2\ dy \geq 0.000186 x^2$$
and on RH one has a matching upper bound
$$ \int_x^{2x} |\psi(y)-y|^2\ dy \leq 0.8603 x^2$$
Thus your desired bound cannot hold for any $a<2$. (If RH fails, then this integral is known to grow strictly faster than $x^2$.)

In that paper several previous results of this type are also discussed. Interestingly, they show that even on RH, the quantity $\frac{1}{x^2} \int_0^x |\psi(y)-y|^2\ dy$ cannot converge to a limiting value as $x \to \infty$, even though it is bounded both above and below (there are terms that oscillate like $x^{i\gamma}$ for some gap $\gamma$ between zeroes).